# I use async waterfall, why callback is not a function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

I get this:

> Error: TypeError: callback is not a function

Code:

```
var async = require('async');

async.waterfall([
  (callback) => {
    callback(null, 'test');
  },
  async (value1, callback) => {
    const data = await send("http://google.com/search?q="+value1);

    callback(null, data); //TypeError: cb is not a function
  }
], (err) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);
});
```

why can it be an error? even though "callback" is the default function of async.waterfall. is it not possible in the async function I put the async function in it?

Answer (score 4):

When you use `async` in a function inside the waterfall, there's no `callback` argument. Instead of calling `callback(null, data)` you resolve `data`.

```
async.waterfall([
  (callback) => {
    callback(null, 'test');
  },
  async value1 => {
    const data = await send("http://google.com");

    return data;
  },
  (value1, callback) => {
     // value1 is the resolve data from the async function
  }
], (err) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);
});
```

From the [docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html):

> Wherever we accept a Node-style async function, we also directly
>   accept an ES2017 async function. In this case, **the async function will
>   not be passed a final callback argument**, and any thrown error will be
>   used as the err argument of the implicit callback, and the return
>   value will be used as the result value. (i.e. a rejected of the
>   returned Promise becomes the err callback argument, and a resolved
>   value becomes the result.)